# XSLT Transform content of elements without children to attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT transformations and here's what I've been trying to do all evening and I hope to get your help:
I have an XML structure like this:

```
   <DEV>
       <HDR>
           <ApID>value1</ApID>
           <STAT>value2</STAT>
       </HDR>
       <DSC>
           <Cap>value3</Cap>
       </DSC>
   </DEV>
```

basically I need to translate all values of elements without children into attributes with name "V":

```
<DEV>
    <HDR>
        <ApID V= "value1" />
        <STAT V= "value2" />
    </HDR>
    <DSC>
        <Cap V = "value3" />
    </DSC>
</DEV>
```

Is there any way to write a generic transformation like that with XSLT?

Answer (score 2):

XSLT lets you recursively traverse the node tree. Whilst traversing your tree, you can get XSLT to process your nodes by creating template rules that are more specific than other template rules.

The problem you are trying to solve is in transforming your XML tree with some slight differences. A good start is to take the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This identity transform will simply produce the XML output that is the same as the input XML. It matches and copies every XML node as it is. You then mould your output step-by-step until you get what you want.  See documentation for `<xsl:copy/>`.

The exception to this copying you want to make is when you come across elements that do not have any child nodes. To match any element, we use `*`. to match no elements, we use `not(*)`. To match any element with no elements, we thus use `*[not(*)]`. In fact, these rules are defined by the [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query language which XSLT uses. Let's try the following XSLT against your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <found-an-element-with-no-children/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DEV>
    <HDR>
        <found-an-element-with-no-children/>
        <found-an-element-with-no-children/>
    </HDR>
    <DSC>
        <found-an-element-with-no-children/>
    </DSC>
</DEV>
```

The nice thing is that any one node can only match against a single template rule at a time. And we look much closer to where we want to be now.

Here's where `<xsl:copy/>` comes in.  We'll use it now because we want to copy the original element's name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <found-an-element-with-no-children/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now we get to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DEV>
    <HDR>
        <ApID><found-an-element-with-no-children/></ApID>
        <STAT><found-an-element-with-no-children/></STAT>
    </HDR>
    <DSC>
        <Cap><found-an-element-with-no-children/></Cap>
    </DSC>
</DEV
```

Now add an attribute to our newly created node, and include in it the text contents of the node that we matched just now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="V">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it looks like we're here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DEV>
    <HDR>
        <ApID V="value1"/>
        <STAT V="value2"/>
    </HDR>
    <DSC>
        <Cap V="value3"/>
    </DSC>
</DEV>
```

Now a couple of pointers:

1. None of your `ApID`, `STAT` and `Cap` will be able to copy its old attributes. You will want to include `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` to include those attributes.
2. And when you include those attributes, what happens if the original input contains a `V` attribute?
3. You might want to additionally consider what happens when the tags that you match have no text - and why.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes"! Firstly, you would base your XSLT upon the [XSLT identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). On its own, this copies all the nodes an attributes in your XML

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

By using this, you only then need to write templates to match the nodes you wish to transform. In your case, you say you want to match elements without children (although strictly speaking, the elements do have children. They have text nodes as children! But I guess you mean they don't have other elements as children). So, your template match would look this this

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
```

Where `*` is the symbol used to match elements.

Then, within this template, you can copy the element, and turn the text into an attribute using **xsl:attribute**

```
     <xsl:attribute name="V">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
     </xsl:attribute>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="V">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<DEV>
  <HDR>
    <ApID V="value1" />
    <STAT V="value2" />
  </HDR>
  <DSC>
   <Cap V="value3" />
  </DSC>
</DEV>
```

Comment: doesn't order of template rule matter here? I mean does the processing continue after completing the `match="@*|node()"` one?

Comment: XSLT has the concept of template priority. Where two templates can match the same node, it will give priority to the template that is more specific (i.e the one with the condition present here). You can read about it at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict if you want!